# visual studio connection to sql server

Tags: c#

when i click on the add connection, it shows a message as Event_log file is full.Why is this happening?? Please help!!!!

Comment: Have you looked in eventvwr.exe to see what state your event-logs are in? It sounds like at least one of them simply needs trimming...

Comment: Can you show us the error message (a screenshot)? Have you tried using the Event Viewer to check your event log? Possibly delete all the entries in the Event log and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: ya I deleted the entries in the event viewer from control panel and now its fine working.

Answer (score 2):

It clearly says that your Event_log file is full. Check it.